# Autohotkey Window-ID

Tags: autohotkey

can somebody help me, I took a script and modified the parts I dont need with comments. Now I want to change the way the script is working by a little bit.

Alt+4 Posts the WIndow-ID of the active window in a popup

Alt+3 Brings the Editor in front/focus

Alt+2 Brings the Internet Explorer in front/focus

Now i want that the IE and the Edititor are not put in focus cause of there names, I want that they are in focus cause of there Window-ID.

How can i do that? Is that possible? In the documentation i dont find a possibility to put in a ID by ifwinaktive [Doku](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm)

```
!4::
WinGet, active_id, ID, A
MsgBox, The active window's ID is "%active_id%".
return

!3::ToggleWindow("Editor")
!2::ToggleWindow("Internet")


ToggleWindow(TheWindowTitle)
{
    SetTitleMatchMode,2
    DetectHiddenWindows, Off
    IfWinActive, %TheWindowTitle%
    {
       ;;;;; WinMinimize, %TheWindowTitle%
    }
    Else
    {
        IfWinExist, %TheWindowTitle%
        {
            WinActivate
            ;;;;; Tried using WinMaximize/WinRestore here but same result
        }
        Else
        {
            ;;;;; DetectHiddenWindows, On
            ;;;;; IfWinExist, %TheWindowTitle%
            ;;;;; {
            ;;;;;     WinShow
            ;;;;;     WinActivate
            ;;;;; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your problem right: You want to use `ifWinActive` on distinct process IDs.

There are several ways to determine your window. Also see [WinTitle](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) for reference. I'm gonna copy you some text which I had once already sent a buddy of mine.

### WinTitle parameters that usually don't change:

```
; ahk_class does not change after program restart
; find out the ahk_class name with WindowSpy
ifWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
    msgBox

; process name usually does not change.
; find it out using TaskManager or winGet
ifWinActive, ahk_exe Notepad.exe
    msgBox
```

### WinTitle parameters that may change from time to time:

```
; the TITLE of the window, like "Editor" or "google.com".
; find it out using your eyes.
ifWinActive, Editor
    msgBox

; window TEXT.
; find it out using WindowSpy
setTitleMatchMode, slow
ifWinActive,, hi. some text which I typed in the editor
    msgBox
setTitleMatchMode, fast
; Note: you can also make use of ExcludeTitle and ExcludeText. see ifWinActive
```

### WinTitle parameters that certainly change after a restart of the respective program:

note: for identifying a window distinctly, one of these will be your preferred method. There is but one ID / PID per running process.

```
; unique ID / HWND does change, you'll have to retrieve it with something stable:
winGet, editor_hwnd, ID, ahk_class Notepad
ifWinActive, ahk_id %editor_hwnd%
    msgBox

; process ID also varies:
winGet, editor_pid, PID, ahk_class Notepad
ifWinActive, ahk_pid %editor_pid%
    msgBox
```

---

so, in your example, you could maybe use

```
!3::ToggleWindow("ahk_class Notepad")
```

or use one of the examples above.

Comment: that's cool! please consider answering and accepting your own answer then.

Comment: WinActivate, ahk_id IDhere